# Meaning of rock the world

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, american-english

Is the sentence "**Let's rock the world**" correct? 
The intention is to communicate to a friend that we together will do a great business and make lots of money

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you'd like to know?  What does "correct" mean?

Comment: @Juhasz, I mean, does it convey the meaning that we will make a lot of money and do fantastic work in the future together. In an online dictionary, I found that `rock the world` can be used like `You must try that new car it will rock your world`, so here it is expressing to the other person that he will like it. But the way I am using it, there is no other person. Or consider the sentence `We will rock the world` it could mean that the world will like it by dictionary definition. But I intended to convey that we are going to do great business and make lots of money and do awesome stuff.

Comment: @Juhasz `We will rock the world` probably by dictionary definition doesn't have any person or the world who will like it. The thing we are planning to do will just benefit us. Thinking in this way this sentence seems incorrect for the given situation.

Answer (score 1):

To rock someone's world is an idiom which means that something is so amazing that they will definitely like it. For example - This latest tesla model is so good that it will rock your world. But i guess you can also use it if you want to tell that you want to shake the world in some way with a great business idea. Like - With our business plan, together we can rock the world! I hope that i answered your question.